# need to verify the name and i have found the below error with code

Tags: python

```
Login=input("your name please")
if LoginName == ("Ahmed")
 print("valid name")
else:
 print("invalid name")
```

pleas advise what is the wrong here

cheek error message

```
if LoginName ==("Ahmed")
                        ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you need to add `: ` after the if similar to the `else` so that it reads `if LoginName == 'Amed':`

Comment: Friendly hint: You should read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 2):

1. You've missed a `:` after the `if-statement`.
2. The `LoginName` is not defined; you should use `Login` instead in the `if-statement`
3. The paranthesis around the `"Ahemd"` is unnecessary.

```py
Login=input("your name please")
if Login == "Ahmed":  #<---- 
 print("valid name")
else:
 print("invalid name")
```

Comment: Parentheses don't make a tuple. A comma does. Run `a = 1,` and `print(type(a))` and see for yourself.

Comment: Thank you , @Matthias 

Comment: Nevertheless the parentheses are superfluous and just make the code look more complicated so I totally agree with you that they should be removed.

Comment: thanks  brother  @BehdadAbdollahiMoghadam Abdollahi Moghadam

Comment: Anytime  @AhmedSriea

Comment: Hi @AhmedSriea , How are you doing brother? I just want to mention that if my answer was useful and helpful for you, I'll be so delighted to give it an upvote  or even choose it as the correct answer ✅ Cheers 